# Parsing XML with embedded data

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

Im trying to parse an XML using android. My problem is that the XML is in a strange format. The entirety of the data I'm trying to parse is located inside one element.

Here is an example:

```
<a name="3"></a>
<div class="series_alpha">
<h2 class="series_alpha"><a href="#top">3</a></h2>
<ul class="series_alpha"><li><a href="/3-banme-no-kareshi">3 Banme no        Kareshi</a><span class="mangacompleted">[Completed]</span></li>
<li><a href="/1074/3-gatsu-no-lion.html">3 Gatsu no Lion</a></li>
<li><a href="/990/337-byooshi.html">337 Byooshi</a></li>
<li><a href="/360-degrees-material">360 Degrees Material</a></li>
<li><a href="/37-degrees-kiss">37 Degrees Kiss</a><span class="mangacompleted">[Completed]</span></li>
<li><a href="/184/3x3-eyes.html">3x3 Eyes</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

The XML is a piece of the source from [this](http://www.mangapanda.com/alphabetical) webpage. The data I'm trying to retrieve is found in the `<li>` tag, specifically the link reference and Manga name. But I dont know how I would separate the link from the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking it up I found the information inside the tags is known as an "attribute" (I'm a noob i know) and with some google searches found the `attributes.getvalue("name of attribute here")` method is what I was looking for.

source: [XML Parsing to get Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594184/xml-parsing-to-get-attribute-value)